# Limit wildcard capture length postgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

Is there a way to limit the number of characters a wildcard '%' operator looks at? Say I wanted to select only records with two occurrences of the phrase 'July', I would include " LIKE '%July%July' " in my query, but now I only want to select if the two Julys are within 40 characters of each other. Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about use a [Regular Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)?

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn ~ 'July.{0,40}July';
```

(Note: Use `~*` instead of `~` to get a case-insensitive match.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aeeb2/3)